# How to use Maple to eliminate parameters in surface vector equation to obtain equation in Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maple

Consider the surface given by the vector equation

$$\vec{r}(u,v)=(x_0+a_1 u+b_1v)\hat{i}+(x_0+a_2u+b_2v)\hat{j}+(z_0+a_3u+b_3v)\hat{k}\tag{1}$$

and the task of eliminating parameters $u$ and $v$ to obtain a Cartesian equation.

I think one way is to simply try to make substitutions.

This is what I tried in Maple

```
x := (u, v) -> x__0 + a__1*u + b__1*v
y := (u, v) -> y__0 + a__2*u + b__2*v
z := (u, v) -> z__0 + a__3*u + b__3*v
r := (u, v) -> <x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v)>

# Solve for u
solve(x(u, v) = x, u)

# Copy previous output and sub into equation for y(u,v), solve for v
solve(eval(y(u, v) = y, u = -(b__1*v - x + x__0)/a__1), v)

# Copy previous output and sub into previously found u
simplify(eval(-(b__1*v - x + x__0)/a__1, v = (a__1*y - a__1*y__0 - a__2*x + a__2*x__0)/(a__1*b__2 - a__2*b__1)))

# Sub in previous results for u and v into z(u,v)
simplify(eval(z(u, v) = z, {u = ((-y + y__0)*b__1 + b__2*(x - x__0))/(a__1*b__2 - a__2*b__1), v = (a__1*y - a__1*y__0 - a__2*x + a__2*x__0)/(a__1*b__2 - a__2*b__1)}))
```

The result of this isn't a pretty looking expression.

[image]

What I would like to do is have Maple simplify this expression by collecting terms that multiple $x-x_0$, $y-y_0$, and $z-z_0$. **How do I do this?**

Doing this with pen and paper gives the correct result, which is

$$(a_2b_3-a_3b_2)(x-x_0)+(a_3b_1-a_1b_3)(y-y_0)+(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)(z-z_0)=0$$

**Is there a better way to solve this problem in Maple?**

Is there a better way to solve the problem in general?

Answer (score 1):

Here are your equations,

```
x := (u, v) -> x__0 + a__1*u + b__1*v:
y := (u, v) -> y__0 + a__2*u + b__2*v:
z := (u, v) -> z__0 + a__3*u + b__3*v:

eqs := [x(u,v)-x, y(u,v)-y, z(u,v)-z];

     eqs := [a__1 u + b__1 v - x + x__0,
             a__2 u + b__2 v - y + y__0, 
             a__3 u + b__3 v - z + z__0]
```

The steps you showed above can be done together as,

```
H := eliminate(eqs, [u,v])[2];

    H := {a__1 b__2 z - a__1 b__2 z__0 - a__1 b__3 y + a__1 b__3 y__0
          - a__2 b__1 z + a__2 b__1 z__0 + a__2 b__3 x - a__2 b__3 x__0
          + a__3 b__1 y - a__3 b__1 y__0 - a__3 b__2 x + a__3 b__2 x__0}
```

And now you asked about collecting w.r.t. `x-x__0`, `y-y__0`, and `z-z__0`.

We can use the following equations for temporary substitutions. The second list is just the reverse of the first. I assign them to names just for convenience (and so that you can see them here).

```
S := Equate([x-x__0,y-y__0,z-z__0], [X,Y,Z]);

    S := [x - x__0 = X, y - y__0 = Y, z - z__0 = Z]

rS := (rhs=lhs)~(S); # reversed

    rS := [X = x - x__0, Y = y - y__0, Z = z - z__0]
```

And now we can collect w.r.t. to those new names `X,Y,Z`, simplifying the coefficients (though not necesary here), and then resubstitute back to the original names (terms).

```
sol := eval(collect(simplify(H, S), [X,Y,Z], simplify), rS);

    sol := {(a__2 b__3 - a__3 b__2) (x - x__0)
          + (-a__1 b__3 + a__3 b__1) (y - y__0)
          + (a__1 b__2 - a__2 b__1) (z - z__0)}
```

If it helps your understanding, that could be done in steps,

```
temp := simplify(H, S);

    temp := {(a__1 b__2 - a__2 b__1) Z + X a__2 b__3
       + (-X b__2 + Y b__1) a__3 - Y a__1 b__3}

temp2 := collect(temp, [X,Y,Z], simplify);

    temp2 := {(a__2 b__3 - a__3 b__2) X
              + (-a__1 b__3 + a__3 b__1) Y
              + (a__1 b__2 - a__2 b__1) Z}

eval(temp2, rS);

        {(a__2 b__3 - a__3 b__2) (x - x__0)
          + (-a__1 b__3 + a__3 b__1) (y - y__0)
          + (a__1 b__2 - a__2 b__1) (z - z__0)}
```

There is a possibility that some of your terms might be ordered different from your target, eg, `-z__0+z`  instead of desired `z-z__0`. In such a case you could force them to appear in your desired form by,

```
sort(sol, order=plex(x,y,z));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about *polynomials*:

```
polys = {x0 + a1 u + b1 v - x, y0 + a2 u + b2 v - y, z0 + a3 u + b3 v - z};
```

the general idea is to determine a *Gröbner basis* of the type:

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, {v, u, z, y, x}]
```

> {-a3 b2 x + a2 b3 x + a3 b2 x0 - a2 b3 x0 + a3 b1 y - a1 b3 y - a3 b1 y0 + a1 b3 y0 - a2 b1 z + a1 b2 z + a2 b1 z0 - a1 b2 z0, -a3 b2 u + a2 b3 u - b3 y + b3 y0 + b2 z - b2 z0, -a3 b1 u + a1 b3 u - b3 x + b3 x0 + b1 z - b1 z0, -a2 b1 u + a1 b2 u - b2 x + b2 x0 + b1 y - b1 y0, a3 u + b3 v - z + z0, a2 u + b2 v - y + y0, a1 u + b1 v - x + x0}

where the first polynomial of this basis is the desired one:

```
FullSimplify[First[gb]]
```

> a3 b2 (x - x0) + a2 b3 (-x + x0) + a1 b3 (y - y0) + a3 b1 (-y + y0) + a2 b1 (z - z0) + a1 b2 (-z + z0)

If then, as happens in *Mathematica*, there's a dedicated command, even better:

```
Eliminate[polys == {0, 0, 0}, {u, v}]
```

> a3 b2 x0 - a2 b3 x0 + a3 b1 y - a1 b3 y - a3 b1 y0 + a1 b3 y0 - 
> a2 b1 z + a1 b2 z + a2 b1 z0 - a1 b2 z0 == (a3 b2 - a2 b3) x

It's up to you to consult the *Maple documentation* for similar functions.

Comment: Is this Gröbner basis the answer to the question of how to collect the terms in the expression in blue in my post, or is it the answer to the question of what a better way to solve the problem is?